# script to execute commands for all the users on ubuntu server

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line

I am running a script through `root` which will do login to all the registered users and will execute few commands(example: list down all the folders in users directory), collect their reports and copy it in root login.

My command looks like this

```
for i in `cat userlist`; do echo $i; su $i ; ls ; exit; done > folderList
```

The problem with this command is after doing a `su` to user it changes the shell and the script waits till it receives a exit from that shell

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
su - $user -c whoami
```

for executing a command as user in a subshell, which is terminated automatically when program ends.